# How to bind a repeater to an array of a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class like this

```
    public class Link
    {
        public string LinkID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
    }
```

and a method that returns an array of `Link[]`

Could I bind that to a repeater, which will reference the Title and URL from Link?
How do I reference it? `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>` doesn't make anything show up

edit:This is embarrassing..I forgot that I emptied the database a couple days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are setting your DataSource and then Binding:

```
YourRepeater.DataSource = GetArray();
YourRepeater.DataBind();
```

Once everything is bound, you can reference the items in your repeater:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval( Container.DataItem, "Title" ) %>
```

or

```
<%# Eval( "Title" ) %>
```

Comment: This is embarrassing..I forgot that I emptied the database a couple days ago and there was nothing to show..

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your are properly binding your array of Link objects to the repeater, this should work:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link.Title") %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `"Link.Title"` be just `"Title"`?

Comment: not according to my findings, did some googling and found so :)

Comment: I haven't seen that notation before. Could you post a link demonstrating the usage?

Comment: "Title" is working for me, "Link.Title" throws this  `does not contain a property with the name 'Link'`